# ISO or VHD for MCSA exam training?

Tags: windows-server-2012

First, please excuse me if my question is not at the right place.

I'd like to pass the Windows 2012 MCSA exams, and I've chosen some books.
But, is there a way to get a Windows Server license or ISO ou whatever just for training ?

Thanks,

Jérémie

Comment: Training providers will generally provide you with the necessary software to complete a course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 180-days evaluation term of Windows Server 2012 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012) is pretty enougth for prerarations to any exam..

Comment: It seems to be the right way according to my self-sutdying will. Спасибо ;)